# Display data from kobuki to android through bluetooth

Tags: ros, bluetooth, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a kobuki. And a lap setup Ros. I need transfer data from this laptop to Android. Anyone have suggest about send data  by C, C++ through bluetooth to Android please help me.
I can connect between ubuntu lap and Android by bluetooth. But I don't know how it can send data. Anyone have example, tutorial about send data by C, C++ and receive by Android help me :(. I very need it. Sorry my English is not good

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207468/display-data-from-kobuki-to-android-through-bluetooth/) by [Mai](https://answers.ros.org/users/20937/mai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. I can't compile with rosandroid.
I send data through bluetooth. In linux, code C write data into rfcomm0 port and in android device create a socket received data from rfcomm0 port. You can find it in Bluetooth Chat example

---

Originally posted by [Mai](https://answers.ros.org/users/20937/mai/) with karma: 16 on 2015-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0